# Undefined property of an undefined object in if else clause

Tags: javascript

There is a LS object in the app scope which, depending on the web page section, contains the product or the category property. So I have to check that and save data in the localStorage. This is the code:

```
if (LS.product !== 'undefined') {

      data = {
          'prod_id' :   LS.product['id'], 
          'prod_name' : LS.product['name'],
          'prod_price' : LS.variants[0]['price_number'],
          'category' : '' //TODO
       }
      item_name = String('product-' + LS.product['id']) + '-' + String(Date.now());
      localStorage.setItem(item_name, JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  else if (LS.category !== 'undefined') {
      data = {
          'category_id' :   LS.category['id'], 
          'category_name' : LS.category['name'],
       }
      item_name = String('category-' + LS.category['id']) + '-' + String(Date.now());
      localStorage.setItem(item_name, JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  else {
      data = {};
  }
```

The problem is that I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

But works fine if I only execute the corresponding section of the code. I have been trying to find an solution but had no success.

Comment: The string `'undefined'` is just a string, and not at all the same thing as the value `undefined`.

Comment: Where does the error appear, at `LS.product['id']` or at `LS.category['id']`?

Comment: if (typeof LS.category !== 'undefined')

Comment: And @Pointy is right, you should use `if (LS.product !== undefined) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check for `undefined` as the undefined value, not as a string being `'undefined'`

```
if (LS.product !== 'undefined') {
...
else if (LS.category !== 'undefined') {
```

Should be

```
if (LS.product !== undefined) {
...
else if (LS.category !== undefined) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking against the string `"undefined"` rather than the value `undefined`. Try `if (LS.product !== undefined) {` and `else if (LS.category !== undefined) {`